# Adjoint operator of generalized Volterra operator $\int_{0}^{t} f(t-s)g(s) ds$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $f \in C(\mathbb{R})$, $g\in L^2([0,a])$ (where $a$ is finite) and we define 
$(Vg)(t):=\int_{0}^{t} f(t-s)g(s) ds.$

Then I want to find the operator $V^*,$ i.e. $$\langle Vg,h \rangle_{L^2[0,a]} = \langle g,V^*h \rangle_{L^2[0,a]}.$$

This operator somehow reminded me of the Volterra operator, but now there is  a mean integral kernel there additionally. Does anybody know how to determine this one?

Comment: That "mean integral kernel" is one you should recognize.

Comment: @Math1000 what does that "mean"? Does this operator have a well-known name?

Comment: Yes, it is the convolution of $f$ with $g$.

Comment: @Math1000 Convolution would integrate from $0$ to $a$, not $0$ to $t$.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that part. I would still consider it the convolution of $f$ with $g$ on $[0,a]$ though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\langle V g, h\rangle=\int_0^adt\int_0^tds\, \overline{g(s)}\, h(t)\, \overline{f(t-s)}=\int_0^adt\int_0^ads\, \overline{g(s)}\chi_{[0,t]}(s)\, h(t)\, \overline{f(t-s)}\\
=\int_0^ads\, \overline{g(s)}\int_0^a dt\, h(t)\, \overline{f(t-s)}\,\chi_{[0,t]}(s)=\langle g, V^* h\rangle$$
where $$V^*h(s)=\int_0^adt\, \chi_{[0,t]}(s)\,\overline{f(t-s)} \,h(t)=\int_s^a dt\ \overline{f(t-s)}\, h(t)$$

Answer (score 0):

Neal wrote: Convolution would integrate from $0$ to $a$, not $0$ to $t$.

Not necessarily.  Although Wikipedia isn't authoritative, its article on Convolution gives the formula
$$(f*g)(t)=\int_0^t f(\tau)g(t-\tau)\,\mathrm{d}t$$
for functions supported only on the positive real axis.

The operator 
$$f\mapsto (f*g)(t)=\int_0^t f(\tau)g(t-\tau)\,\mathrm{d}t$$
is a Volterra operator, whereas the operator
$$f\mapsto (f*g)(t)=\int_0^a f(\tau)g(t-\tau)\,\mathrm{d}t$$
is a Fredholm operator (both of the first kind).